# How to send automatically send texts through an app from a third-party (my app) number?

Tags: android, ios

I want a behavior like this:

- User A performs an action
- Action inputs/saves to a server
- User B receives a text from a number that belongs to my app
- User B does not know User A's phone number

This behavior is seen in Groupme, when they add your number to a chat. You don't see anybody else's number, but Groupme itself is sending the information.

Same thing with Remind 101. This app sends mass texts to everyone in the group from the remind number. Anyone can reply back.

**What I have been looking at:**

I have done some tinkering with Telephony SMS on Android, but it only appears to automate sending texts when your number is provided. I have also thought about using Firebase realtime database and sending out text messages through email protocol provided by the carrier, but this is cumbersome and Firebase server does not support email 'trigger' action anymore. 
I have very limited experience on iOS but I would also like to hear solutions that work for this as well.

How does Groupme do it? How does Remind do it? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to send an actual SMS message (rather than an push notification) then you will need to use a service such as Twilio

Comment: refer this:  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are push messages. You can send push messages from your webserver to your app users who subscribed to your push messages.

Look for Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of GCM (now FCM). However, am I correct in saying that it does not use phone numbers at all? Or SMS texting? I understand downstream push messaging is of utility but I don't think it could work in my app.

Comment: From what I understood there's no need to use phone numbers or SMS. If you require sending an SMS, you need to know the number of the destination, there's no way around it. Can you elaborate on "receives text from a number that belongs to my app"? I think I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Correct, I want it to use SMS and the user to input a phone number, if you are familiar with Groupme. Sorry if it was confusing, the number should be like an automated robot number that sends the text on behalf of the app itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with it. I take it your web server is supposed to send the SMS to the recipient, so it's something like an anonymous SMS chat? So if I understand you correctly, user A sends a message to your server along with the phone number of user B, the server then sends a message from your server's number to user B, masking user A's number? Then you just need to use an SMS gateway service. The harder part will be to allow user B to answer back to user A, because he will answer to your server's number and you would have to guess who he wanted to reach (the last dialog partner?)...

Comment: Exactly. SMS gateway service? I will look into that. Thank you for the pointer, will update later.